# Computer will only display output to monitor. Output is scrambled

Tags: windows-7, windows

While I was using my laptop, vertical lines appeared across the screen. I tried to alleviate this issue by restarting the laptop.

After rebooting, the screen remained blank and there was no indication the OS  booted to Windows. I have tried plugging in an external monitor. Occasionally I get a scrambled output on the external monitor. On other occasions it does not work at all. Here is a photo of the output, if you look closely you will see it mentions something about 'Realtek family...' could it be related to a driver or damaged device?

[image: Scrambled output image]

From what I can remember it has 
4GB RAM ram, i5 processor, windows 7, HP ProBook 4520s

Answer (score 1):

That looks like hardware failure.  And if I read the specs right (from HPs website) then this is a laptop without replaceable gaming graphics cards.

That means that:

- You can RMA it if within warranty.
- Or you can write it off.
- Or you can use it without graphics (e.g. as a server or a NAS).
- Or, since it has an expresscard slot, you could try to add an external GPU.

Failing all that the graphics part may be on the CPU die, which in theory is replaceable. On laptops CPUs are often soldered to the motherboard though, making this an *interesting* exercise.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on a Dell m6500 with all external monitors attached as a 2nd screen.
If the mouse can be seen on 2nd screen and is not scrambled it is a software issue.
Replacing video cards, processor and motherboard did not fix it.
A complete reformat and clean install fixed it. (complete data loss)
Did not come back after going to win 8 and then to win 10.
Tried enabling Hyper V in win 10 and it came back.
Removed it hyper V it worked normally again.
Definately software as original occurrence was after an AMD video driver update.